# I like this div that fades in from LTR - how do i do it?

Tags: jquery, transition

Looking at this site https://sunny.co.uk/ i found a transition i like. The main body div fades/slides in from left to right.

I would like to accomplish this but getting confused with all the different jquery functions, animate, slide etc.

Can anyone provide some advice on how this is done? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this, I used to work with it on my previous project.

http://jonobr1.github.com/diagonalFade/

Hope it fits your needs.

or you can try

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/alano/WCtQn/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(element).animate({left:200, opacity:"show"}, 1500);
});
```

and make sure the div is initially hidden `style="display:none;"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this tutorial out, I have used it on a site I am currently building, its very helpful and has lots of nice ideas.  I had to edit the javascript file a lot so a good understanding of that is needed.

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/05/07/a-collection-of-page-transitions/

Thanks